# Sort string list dependent on some conditions in c# with linq

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, sorting

I've a list like this:

```
public static List<List<string>> GraphLists = new List<List<string>>();
```

It contains some data:

[image]

I want to sort these by SECOND item. So, list should be like this:

```
{0-0-44,25}
{1-0-41}
{0-1-28}
{1-1-33}
{0-2-37,33}
{1-2-44,33}
```

How can I do this with linq?

Comment: That list isn't sorted by the first number. So what do you mean? What is an item?

Comment: @weston: It's pretty clear, isn't it? Each list item is a list of strings. He wants to sort the list by the first item in each sub-list.

Comment: Is your third element decimal or is it the items separator?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar your interpretation doesn't match the example given, so no, it's not clear.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar your answer doesn't even match "sort the list by the first item in each sub-list."!

Comment: Sorry, it should be sorted by second item. You are right. Third element is a decimal.

Comment: @weston My answer assumed he wanted to sort `GraphList` by the first item in each sub-list. That way obviously not the case, but given the other answers I wasn't the only one thinking that was what he wanted. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a dirty hack i suppose, but it should give you an idea (of how I'd do it):

first of all create a little dummy class like this

```
class Item
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string second { get; set; }
    public string third { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("0-0-44,25");
list.Add("1-0-41");
list.Add("0-1-28");
list.Add("1-1-33");
list.Add("0-2-37,33");
list.Add("1-2-44,33");

List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    // split all of your strings and put it into the item class and then add it to the list
    string[] parts = item.Split('-');

    items.Add(new Item()
    {
        first = parts[0],
        second = parts[1],
        third = parts[2]
    });
}

// now you're able to sort it (by the second property)
var result = items.OrderBy(x => x.second);

List<string> resultList = new List<string>();

// and now put it back together
foreach (var item in result)
{
    resultList.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", item.first, item.second, item.third));
}
```

All you have to do now is insert back the received list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to order by the second number in the text you need to do a Split so
Here's how I would do it:

```
//order the outer list based on the middle item
var orderedList = GraphLists.OrderBy(x=>x.First().Split('-')[1]);
```

alternative (more accurate) solution:

```
//order the inner lists based on the middle item
GraphLists.ForEach(innerList=>innerList.OrderBy(x=>x.First().Split('-')[1]);
```

Comment: you don't really sort when the items at index 1 are the same

Comment: He can also do ThenBy, but from the question it needs second item sorting only,

Comment: yes I agree, this precision isn't given in the question but, from the example, I've got the feeling that the following elements at index 2, 3, etc have to be take into account. ThenBy should do the job if you're sure you've got the elements

Comment: That depends where that data come from and many other information the user hasn't provided

Comment: no, I agree with you, your reponse clearly answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot of interpretation been going on in the question's comments. So I tell you what I understand now:

You have a list `GraphList` where each item is a list of strings. One string can look like this:

```
"0-1-44,33"
```

or generically

```
"x-y-z"
```

with `z` being a decimal number.

Now you want each of these "item lists" (elements of `GraphList`) to be sorted by the second component (`y`) of the string. However, your desired result shows that you want to order by `y` first and then by `x`, so the solution presented in my original answer gives the hint:

You get a sorted "item list" by

```
var subList = GraphList.Items[i].OrderBy(x => 
              {
                  var split = x.Split('-');
                  return split[1].PadLeft(5, '0') + split[0].PadLeft(5, '0');
              });
```

I've used the following sample code to change `GraphList` to only contain sorted sub-lists:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<string>> GraphList = new List<List<string>>();
        GraphList.Add(new List<string>() { "0-2-37", "0-0-44", "0-1-28", "1-0-41", "1-2-44", "1-1-33" });
        GraphList.Add(new List<string>() { "2-2-37", "2-0-44", "2-1-28", "3-0-41", "3-2-44", "3-1-33" });
        GraphList.Add(new List<string>() { "4-2-37", "4-0-44", "4-1-28", "5-0-41", "5-2-44", "5-1-33" });

        for (int i = 0; i < GraphList.Count; i++)
        {
            GraphList[i] = GraphList[i].OrderBy(x =>
            {
                var split = x.Split('-');
                return split[1].PadLeft(5, '0') + split[0].PadLeft(5, '0');
            }).ToList();
        }
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I would do this:

```
var z = l.OrderBy(x => x.First().Substring(2, 1) + x.First().Substring(0, 1));
```

This orders the list `l` by the character after the first `-` concatenated with the first character of the first item in each sub-list.

In your example, the list is ordered by

```
00
01
10
11
20
21
```

Please note that this assumes that there's only just one digit at every position.

If you need more than one digit, you can adapt this to use `String.Split` and `String.PadLeft` to generate fixed size sort criteria. In the following example I pad to a width of 5 digits, so it sorts by:

```
0000000000
0000000001
0000100000
0000100001
0000200000
0000200001
```

This can be achieved by:

```
var z = l.OrderBy(x => 
        {
            var split = x.First().Split('-');
            return split[1].PadLeft(5, '0') + split[0].PadLeft(5, '0');
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Take care that each list has to contain at least one element:

GraphLists.OrderBy(x => x.First());